# Will adding onclick in HTML and calling from Javascript conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I've an anchor link which has an onclick event attached to it. Basically a Facebook share popup opens on clicking it.

```
<a target="_blank" 
   href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=MYLINK" 
   onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"
>Share on Facebook</a>
```

Now I want to track it with Google Analytics Universal Tracking Event Tracking.
So I added a class named `track` to the each anchor that I want to track. My intention is to run the following javascript code

```
$('.track').click(function (e) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
});
```

where `click` and `nav-buttons` values will be dynamically inserted through HTML5 data variables. (which will be attached to the anchor)

```
<a target="_blank" class="track"
   href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=MYLINK" 
   data-event="click"
   data-label="nav-buttons"
   onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"
>Share on Facebook</a>
```

How to integrate the whole thing? Will two onclick event work? Or only one will work?
What is the best way to implement this. Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to remove things from `onclick` and use the same method for both — which would be to use jQuery to add the event listeners.

```
$('.track').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ga('send', e.type, 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
});

$('a.facebookshare').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(this.href, '',
    'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600'
  );
});
```

So you would then use the following markup:

```
<a target="_blank" class="track facebookshare"
  href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=MYLINK" 
  data-label="nav-buttons"
  >Share on Facebook</a>
```

I've removed the `data-event` as you can read this from the event object itself.

I implemented a similar thing a while back with the class `ga-track`, I then exposed this functionality by way of an GUI allowing the owner of the site to easily set up tracking events for almost anything... put simply it is a nice approach to keep your tracking generalised so that it can be applied where ever you wish.

Comment: This looks great With Google Tag Manager, we can do that too. But I'm not very comfy with Tag Manager yet and don't want to mess with the data.

Comment: @LittleLebowski Yeah, this was before all the nice newfangled Google stuff :) Not used GTM yet but it does look good.

Comment: Yeah, it looks good. Lacks good documentation. :( Btw, what do you think of @bingjie2680 answer above. Its similar to what you're doing, but instead of another click event, it uses a `if'. Looks better? Any thoughts?

Comment: @LittleLebowski well Bingjie pipped me at the post :) which ever answer is just personal preference really. I like to keep things separate and was aware of the possibility of other share links... Bingjie deserves the accepted answer though imo (+1) already from me.

Comment: Let me try your approach. I looks more modular too.

Answer (score 2):

You don' need onClick event on achors since you are using Jquery, which will keep your html code cleaner:

```
$('.track').click(function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', target.data('event'), target.data('label');
    if(target.hasClass('facebook') {
        window.open(target.attr('href'),'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});


<a target="_blank" class="track facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=MYLINK" 
  data-event="click"
  data-label="nav-buttons"
>Share on Facebook</a>
```

Comment: The problem is I've another button which is for Twitter Share and it doesn't require `window.open` portion. So how to make the code reusable for all anchor links I want to track irrespective of whether there's a `window.open` or not.

Comment: Looks great. Shouldn't I be using `target.data('event')` and `target.data('label')` to get the HTML5 data params?

Comment: Another quick question. Should I let the popup open first instead of the ga data going out first? Would that be faster for the user.

Comment: that does not make any difference in my opinion. so you can do it.

Comment: Ok, it depends on the Ga function, so you are right, it may be better to open the popup first